# Ionic app not working on mobile device

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ionic-framework

I have created an ionic application, where i am accessing the data from a different domain. In order to make it work, have done the following at server side(express):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8100");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",  "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
next();
});
```

As seen, i have set origin to localhost:8100, which is making my application to work and run properly on browser. However, when i create an .apk file and install on my mobile device, its not working i.e. the data is not coming.

Could someone please help me out with this issue. Is the issue arising because of the origin specified ? If yes, is there any solution for the same.

Comment: Have you tried to comment this line with `origin` and run on device?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a cordova whitelist plugin. If yes , check the access origin settings in config.xml and meta tag for security in index.html. validate your settings from https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist